# How to separate ethernet package to 32 bits per pice

Tags: python, shared-memory

I am trying to write some data to some shared memory, and read from other side. but for some other reason, I can only write 32 bits(byte? not sure, should be bits)

this is for a test purpose, the package may just a simple ping package. how I can separate a package or object to many different pics and regroup them together after read.

if python could do this, that will be best. any idea would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python struct package is your friend to handle this
https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html